# What is my RAID configuration?

Tags: windows-7, raid

I inherited the task of IT-guy in our small company from a guy who left recently. I'm trying to understand the configuration of hard drives on one of our machines.

It looks like we have RAID0, which would make sense because the application we're running needs to write a lot of data to the disk(s). Usually we run not more than 2 calculations at the same time, one on drive F: and one on H:.

My questions:

1. If it is RAID0, why are there 2 partitions on each disk?
2. If it is RAID0, wouldn't the entire writing process be slowed down considerably if we run one process on F: and one on H:?

[image: Disk configuration]

Comment: A true RAID would not show up as multiple drives in Windows Disk Management. How many physical disks are in the machine? There is no reason why *not* to have multiple partitions on a RAID - you can really create as many partitions as you want. The number of partitions per disk (or per RAID array) has no connection to whether it is RAID or not.

Comment: There are 4 physical disks. I just saw that drive E: contains duplicate data from drives F: to I:, like in a RAID1 setup of some sorts. Maybe it's just a script that runs somewhere creating copies on E:? Can those instructions be seen somewhere with a special tool?

Comment: My guess is that there's no actual RAID setup of any kind on this machine. Someone just named the drivers hoping to set one up.